# Reg Jenkins jobs to checkout and run in a complex SVN structure

Tags: svn, jenkins

I have a Subversion branch:

```
---->>main  
          subfolder1 ---subsub foldera---subfolderb 
          subfolder2-
```

On same branch different foders are there. I created two Jenkins jobs one on `/main/subfolder1/subfoldera/subfolderb`

Another job created on `main/subfolder2` scheduled by polling whenever commit happens.

And I changed subfolder3 Java files it is running Jenkins two build jobs automatically.

I want to run the 1 Jenkins job only if `/main/subfolder1/subfoldera` `/subfolderb` files changes. And two job only `main/subfolder2` files changes.

Answer (score 0):

If you click **<kbd>Advanced...</kbd>** under the SVN section, there are **Excluded Regions** and **Included Regions** there. These affect the SVN polling. Configure exclusions there if you don't want a project triggered on certain paths.

Can't give you a direct example was your attempt to explain your structure is quite ambiguous